# WordPress and NGINX - permalinks are not working with ending slash

Tags: permalinks, nginx

I have added this line in the nginx configuration file

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent; #adding slash
```

and the permalinks are working fine, but when adding / (please see rewrite rule how i'm adding it) NGINX gives me 404 error.

For example
somedomain.com/post/ThisIsPermaLink (working)
after adding slash
somedomain.com/post/ThisIsPermaLink/ (gives 404 error)

But all this two versions are working on Apache environment.
Apache is redirecting all requests without slashes (somedomain.com/post/ThisIsPermaLink) to somedomain.com/post/ThisIsPermaLink/

So i need same functionality with NGINX

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need this rewrite rule to add forward slash. WordPress will make redirect for you.

I'm using this code to debug redirection:

```
function wpse_287994_debug_redirect( $url ) {

    echo $url;
    die();
}

add_action( 'wp_redirect', 'wpse_287994_debug_redirect' );
```

When I'm trying to visit address `http://example.com/lorem-ipsum` (this page must exists) above script will output `http://example.com/lorem-ipsum/` so redirection to address with forward slash is working.

My ngnix configuration looks like:

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name           example.com;
  root                  /var/www/example;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  index index.php index.html;

  location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {

    include fastcgi.conf;

    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9070;
  }
}
```

In Nginx rewrites are already made by this part `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`.  This part mean something like that.

For location beginning with `/` character try to load file from file system and if there is no such a file rewrite to `index.php` with arguments.

Comment: Why i need adding it when using NGINX and not have it when using Apache?

Comment: You have to add rewrite rules for Apache not Nginx. In Nginx this part already do it for you `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`.  This part mean something like that. For location beginning with `/` character try to load file from file system and if there is no such a file rewrite to index.php with arguments.

Comment: I know about it. But I don't understand why i need WordPress code modification for NGINX. I need NGINX rules solution not PHP code solution.

Comment: The WordPress code which I paste is not needed for forward slash to be working. It is just showing that WordPress is redirecting post by his own without any modification with this Nginx configuration. You can remove it. If you get 404 after redirection to post with forward slash this is problem with Nginx configuration or WordPress configuration/theme/plugin. Clean WordPress installation with this nginx configuration is working fine.

Comment: Yes. I'm getting error 404 when redirecting to "/post/" not "/post"

Answer (score 0):

Thry the following:
Replace:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

with :

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
```

At the nginx config file for your website.

Then at the permalinks (wordpress settings)